# Serialize and deserialize custom type using Newtonsoft.Json without attributes

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I know that there are JsonConverters that I can use for custom serialization/deserialization.
But I do not want to apply this via attributes, rather via code.

My framework has plugin support for serializers and I'm about to add Newtonsoft JSON support now.
And thus, I do not want to add attributes specific for newtonsoft to my types.
Is there any way to apply a JsonConverter to a specific type in any other way?

I would like to do something along the lines of:

```
  serializer.AddTypeHandler(typeof(MyType), serializeFunction, deserializeFunction);
```

Any way except attribs would be nice..

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Json.Net has the concept of a "ContractResolver" that can be used for this purpose.  The easiest way to make a custom resolver is to inherit from `DefaultContractResolver`.  Then you can override the `CreateContract` method to apply converters to specific types as needed.  For example:

```
class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonContract contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);
        if (objectType == typeof(Foo))
        {
            contract.Converter = new FooConverter();
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

You can apply the resolver to the serializer like this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CustomResolver()
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);
```