# JSonConverter not firing for property of my model in a C# WebAPI

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a model in my WebAPI application, written in .NET 4.0 that has a property of type `System.Net.Mime.ContentType`, like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class FileData
{
    private ContentType contentType;
    private long size;
    private string name;

    public ContentType ContentType
    {
        get { return  contentType; }
        set { contentType = value; } 
    }

    ...

    /* same getter/setter logic for the other fields  */
}
```

The model resides in a separate assembly from my web project.

So, the client sends me a JSON message that I need to convert to this class:

```
{
    "size": 12345,
    "contentType": "image/png",
    "name": "avatar.png"
}
```

In order to tell Json.NET how to convert the `ContentType` I have registered a custom `JsonConverter` that I have written for the purpose:

```
JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ContentTypeJsonConverter());
```

In the above code I am referring to the global `JsonFormatter` obeject for the WebApi application.

Thus, when the client sends me the JSON, I am expecting the controller to properly parse the message.

Unfortunately, it fails with an error :

> "Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Net.Mime.ContentType."

I know I can work this around by adding the following code to my `FileData` class:

```
public class FileData
{
    ...

    [JsonConverter(typeof(ContentTypeJsonConverter))]
    public ContentType ContentType { /* Getter and Setter */ }
}
```

but the problem is that I must not introduce dependencies to JSON.NET in the assembly where the `FileData` type resides.

Is there any way to trigger the proper deserialization of the `contentType` member without altering the `FileData` class?

---

In addition to the above I also tried what [Brian Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10263/brian-rogers) suggested:

```
JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CustomResolver();
```

with the following `CustomResolver` implementation:

```
class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);
        if (objectType == typeof(ContentType))
        {
            contract.Converter = new ContentTypeJsonConverter();
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

The result was still the same.

Comment: In the assembly where the deserialization occurs, you could create another POCO just for deserialization w/ the JsonConverter and then copy the values over to the `FileData` class; this would remove any type of dependency to json.net in the other assembly.

Comment: You could also look into TypeDescriptors to dynamically add the attribute at runtime, but that'd be more effort than a simple POCO class and copying the values, IMO.

Comment: Does the `contentType` field in the `FileData` class have a public accessor/mutator pair?  Does your converter implement the `CanConvert` method such that it will return true when the type `System.Net.Mime.ContentType` is passed to it?

Comment: @BrianRogers, yes, the `FileData` has public getter and setter defined for the `ContentType` property, and in the `CanConvert` method I am using: `return typeof(ContentType).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);`

Comment: Are you adding your converter to the existing JsonFormatter in the global configuration?  Or are you adding it to some other JsonFormatter?

Comment: Yes, I will add this info to my post to remove confusion about that. Good pointing that

Comment: Given the information you've provided in your question and comments, I'm not sure why it is not working.  One other thing you could try is to make a custom contract resolver to apply the converter without needing a `[JsonConverter]` attribute.  See [Serialize and deserialize custom type using Newtonsoft.Json without attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22268478/10263).

Comment: @BrianRogers, thank you for pointing out this alternative approach, but it did not seem to work. See the update in my post. What I observe is that the resolver is firing when it should format an output to the client but not when reading the contents of a post request.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me (Web API 2).

Model:

```
[Serializable]
public class FileData
{
    private ContentType contentType;

    public ContentType ContentType
    {
        get { return contentType; }
        set { contentType = value; }
    }
}
```

Custom JSON converter:

```
public class ContentTypeJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(ContentType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return new ContentType((string)reader.Value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((ContentType)value).ToString());
    }
}
```

Converter registration (`WebApiConfig.cs`):

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    ...
    config
        .Formatters
        .JsonFormatter
        .SerializerSettings
        .Converters
        .Add(new ContentTypeJsonConverter());
}
```

Controller:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Post(FileData data)
    {
        return this.Ok(data);
    }
}
```

Request:

```
POST /api/test HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:48278
Content-Length: 36

{
    "contentType": "image/png"
}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?ZDpcd29ya1xUb0REXGFwaVx0ZXN0?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 25 Jul 2016 07:06:02 GMT
Content-Length: 27

{"contentType":"image/png"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I must admit I have not yet created an isolated project to test this, but I believe my current setup is quite close in terms of configuration to yours, and the converter implementation is nearly identical. Can you tell me which exact version of WebAPI and Json.NET you are using? Later today I will have an opportunity to make an isolated project where I can directly apply your code, and will also play with the versions of the libraries if they differ.